# Learning a language while on a project?

Tags: programming-languages

Have you ever tried learning a language while on a project? I have, and from my personal experience I can say that it takes courage, effort, time, thinking, lots of caffeine and no sleep. Sometimes this has to be done without choice, other times you choose to do it; if you are working on a personal project for example.

What I normally do in this kind of situation, and I believe everyone does, is "build" on top of my current knowledge of languages, structures, syntax and logic. What I find difficult to cope with, is the difference of integrity in some cases. Some languages offer a good background for future learning and "language study", they pose as a good source of information or a frame of reference and can give a "firm" grasp of what's to come. Other languages form or introduce a new way of thinking and are harder to get used to.

Sometimes you unintentionally think in a specific language and when introduced to a new way of thinking, a new language, can cause confusion or make you get lost between the "borders" of your new and your current knowledge of languages.

What can be a good solution in this case? What should be used to broaden the knowledge of the new language, a new way of thinking, and maintain or incorporate the current knowledge of other languages inside the "borders" of the new language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find I need to do a project to properly learn a language, but those can be personal projects.  When I learned Python on the job, I first expected (and found) a significant slowdown in my productivity for a while.  I read the standard tutorials, coding standards and I lurked on the Python list for a while, which gave me a much better idea of the best practices of the language.

Doing things like coding dojos and stuff when learning a language can help you get a feel for things. I just recently changed jobs and went back to Java, and I spent some time working on toy programs just to get back in the feel for things (I'm also reading Effective Java, 2nd edition as my previous major experience had been with Java 1.4).

Comment: Python was such a better fit for me that I found that my productivity went up when I switched to it!  However, at that time I was only spending 5% to 10% of my work time programming (and nearly none outside work, as I had just finished an unrelated Masters degree), so YMMV.

Comment: Note that I was comparing Python to Ruby (what I was using previously) and Python 2 months later.

Answer (score 4):

I think, in some respects no matter what the impetus for learning the language, you have to start by imitating good patterns in the new language.  Whether that means finding a good book, with excellent code examples, good on-line tutorials, or following the lead of a more experienced developer, you have to absorb what it means to write good code in a particular language first.  Once you have developed a level of comfort, you can start branching out and and experimenting with alternatives to the patterns that you've learned, looking for ways to apply things you've learned from other languages, but keeping within the "rules" of the language.  Eventually, you'll get to the point where you know you can 'break the rules" that you learned earlier because you have enough experience to know when they do/don't apply.

My personal preference, even when forced to learn a new language, is to start with some throw away code.  Even starting from good tutorials, you'll undoubtedly write code that later you will look back on and not understand how stupid you could have been.  I prefer, if possible, to write as my first foray into a language code that will be thrown away and not come back to haunt me later.  The alternative is to spend a lot of time refactoring as you learn more and more.   Eventually, you'll end up doing this, too.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to mention ALT.NET here

> Self-organizing, ad-hoc community of developers bound by a desire to improve ourselves, challenge assumptions, and help each other pursue excellence in the practice of software development.

So in the spirit of ALT.NET, it is challenging but useful to reach out of your comfort zone to learn new languages. Some things that really helped me are as follows:

1. Understand the history behind a language or script. Knowing evolution helps a lot.
2. Pick the right book. Research StackOverflow and Amazon.com to find the right book to help you ease the growing pains.
3. OOP is fairly common in most of the mature languages, so you can skip many of the chapters related to OOP in many books. Syntax learning will be a gradual process. I commonly bookmark some quick handy guides for that.
4. Read as many community forums as possible to understand the common pitfalls of the new language.
5. Attend some local meetups to interact with the community and share your pains.
6. Take one pitch at a time by building small not so complicated applications and thereby gaining momentum.
7. Make sure you create a reference frame for what you need to learn. Things like how security, logging, multithreading are handled.
8. Be Open minded, you can be critical, but if you hate something then do not learn that language.

Finally, I think it is worthwhile to learn one strong languages like C# or Java, one functional language and one scripting language like ruby or python.

These things helped me tremendously and I think will help all software engineers and architects to really gear for any development environment.

Answer (score 2):

I learned PHP after I was hired to be the project lead on the Zend Framework project.

It helped that I had 20 years of professional programming background, and good knowledge of C, Java, Perl, JavaScript, SQL, etc.  I've also gravitated towards dynamic scripting languages for most of my career.  I've written applications in awk, frameworks in shell, macro packages in troff, I even wrote a forum using only sed.

Things to help learn a language on the job:

- Reading code and documentation.
- Listening to mailing lists and blogs of the community.
- Talking to experts in the language, fortunately several of whom were my immediate teammates.
- Writing practice code, and asked for code reviews and coaching.(`Zend_Console_Getopt` was my first significant PHP contribution).
- Learning the tools that go along with the language.  [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/), [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/), [phpDoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/), [phing](http://phing.info/), etc.

Of course I did apply what I knew from other programming languages.  Many computer science concepts are language-universal.  The differences of a given language are often simply idiomatic, a way of stating something that can be done another way in another language.  This is especially true for languages like Perl or PHP, which both borrow a lot of idioms from earlier languages.

It also helped that I took courses in Compiler Design in college.  Having a good foundation in how languages are constructed makes it easier to pick up new languages.  At some level, they're all just ways of abstracting runtime stacks and object references.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a junior member of the team and don't know the language, this is not necessarily an issue at all.  As long as there is some code review and supervision, you can be a productive.

Language syntax is one issue, but architectural differences are a more important concern.  Many languages are also development platforms, and if you don't have experience with the platform, you don't know how to create a viable solution architecture.  So if you're the project lead or working solo, you'd better have some experience on the platform before you do your design work.

For example, I would say an experienced C# coder with no VB experience would probably survive a VB.NET project just fine.  In fact, it would be more difficult for a developer who only had experience in C#/ASP.NET to complete a C# WPF project than a VB ASP.NET project.  An experienced PHP developer might hesitate a bit on a ColdFusion project, but they probably won't make any serious blunders because they are familiar with a script based web development architecture.

Many concepts, such as object modelling and database query strategies, translate just fine between languages.  But there is always a learning curve for a new platform, and sometimes it can be quite nasty.  The worst case is that the project must be thrown out because the architure is too wrong to refactor.

Answer (score 1):

I like to learn a new language while working on a project, because a *real* project will usually force me to learn aspects of the language that I might otherwise skip.  One of the first things I like to to is read code in that language, and jump in.  I find resources (such as books and various internet sites) to help as I go along.

Then, after I've been working on it for a while, I like to read (or re-read) books or other resources on the language.  By this time I have some knowledge, so this will help solidify some things and also point out areas where I am flat-out wrong in my understanding.  For instance, I can see that I was making incorrect assumptions about similarities between languages.

This also applies to tools -- after using a tool for a while and learning the basics, reading (or skimming) the documentation can teach me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should try to avoid that. I know, most of the times you can't but in any case try not to mix the new language with the old one, and never add to the mixture old habits, practices and patterns.

Always try to find resources that will help you get through the new language in the way the language works, not in the way other languages do; that will never have a happy ending, and if it does it will be very hard to modify it to the right way.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have.

I mean, is there another way? The only language I ever learned that was not on a project was ABC basic, which was what you used on my first computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend if you start with a certain language, stick with it.  I only say that because many times in the past I tried more and more different ones, and the one I started out with was the best :D

Answer (score 0):

Everytime I have/want to learn a new language, I force myself to find something to code.

But to be sure I did it well, I always want to be able to check my code and what it ouputs.

To do so, I just try to do the same kind of stuff with languages I know and to compare the outputs. For that, I created a little project (hosted on [Github](https://github.com/MrST4N/ProgrammingLearning/)) with an exercise sheet and the correction for every language I learnt. It's a good way to learn in my opinion because it gives you a real little project.